# GooglePlayServicesUtil cannot be found after update

Tags: android

I have been using Google Play Services as part of my project for a few months. I'm using eclipse.

I updated all my sdks etc through the sdk manager on November 1st. Now eclipse can't find the import for the GooglePlayServicesUtil class. I was using it as described here:

http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html#ensure

example:

```
if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(context) 
    == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) 
{
    ...
}
```

Even though I updated google play services and all my sdks via the sdk manager, my workspace has a local copy of the google play services lib (as instructed by the google dev page). So I'm not sure if my sdk manager updates could have affected the copy of gps. Has anyone else experienced this? Searching around it seems like the documentation page (linked above) is still the same as it has been for the last few months.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you testing on your emulator? If so, you need to use an emulator which matches your Google Play Service library.

If this happens in compile time, right-click on the project name --> Build Path --> Configure Build Path --> Order and Export. Make sure the Google Play Service jar is checked. If it is not in the list of entries in Order and Export, go to Libraries and click Add JARs to include the library in your project. If you intend to use the latest version that you downloaded via the SDK Manager, make sure you include the JAR that is in the SDK folder.

If that does not work, put the jar into the libs subdirectory of your project.

Comment: This is at the compilation stage.